# Is there a way to export all the strings for a certain module in x64dbg?

Tags: x64dbg, strings

I have an encrypted file that I was able to step through the code until that specific DLL file was decrypted in memory and I was able to list all of its strings. It has a ton of them that I would like to export all of them to a text file or even a CSV file if possible but I can't find any way to do so.

Am I missing a command or a button somewhere or is this something I would need to try and write a script to accomplish?

Comment: In which window do you have the strings listed?

Comment: It is under references

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try `right click`->`Copy`->`Full Table` to copy it to clipboard.

<s>If you want to copy only strings without `Disassembly` and `Address` columns, right click at the upper bar of this window (where you see `Strings`, `Disassembly` and `Address`), select columns to hide and click the `Hide` button as illustrated below.</s>

[image]

Edit: this will copy the entire table too, so if you want to have only strings saved in a file, you need to delete the two remaining columns.

You may for instance use `Notepad++` for this purpose: navigate to the last line, select everything in this line, except the string, press `Alt`+`Shift`+`PageUp` and keep it pressed until you reach the top of file and while you are there, press `Delete`.

If your file is so big that the above way to delete these columns is impractcical, you may use regular expressions instead.

Comment: I knew I was missing something... Thank you so much! I am braindead after staring at x64dbg for like 12h straight lol.